# jQuery UI Sortable - pass additional data with serialize

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

In the below code, I also want to pass the value `listing_id` in my AJAX post:

```
$('#listing .images').sortable({
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    update: function(event, ui){
        var data = $(this).sortable('serialize');
        var listing_id = $('#listing').attr('data-id');

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: 'listings/sortimages',
            data: data,
            success: function(result){
                alert('Successfully re-ordered items.');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I have tried:

`data.push({name: 'listing_id', value: listing_id});`

It says `data.push is not a function`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
data.push({name: 'listing_id', value: listing_id});
```

doesn't work because `data` is a serialized **string**. Try

```
data += '&listing_id=' + listing_id;
```